# using iterator with a vector of objects c++

Tags: c++, object, vector, erase

i have class contains a `ofstream` file, i face problem when using iterator to delete
an object of a vector of objects of this class.

Here is the error:

`Error 10 error C2249: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::operator =' : no accessible path to private member declared in virtual base 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream`

Code:

```
static vector<VOIP> calls;
...
for(...)
{
    VOIP v = VOIP(...);
    calls.push_back(v);
}
...
for( int i = 0 ; i < calls.size() ; i++)
{
    if(...)
    {
        vector<VOIP>::iterator it = calls.begin() + i;
        calls.erase(it);//"?"
        break;
    }
}
```

Face Error C2249 raises from line "?", any help
and this is the class

```
class VOIP
{
public:
    VOIP(string SourceDirectoryPath, string startTime, signalling sig, int callerIp[], int calleeIp[], int callerPort, int calleePort);
    VOIP(const VOIP & voip);
    ~VOIP(void);
    //caller and callee voice vectors 
    vector<u_char> callerVoiceVector;
    vector<u_char> calleeVoiceVector;
    //caller and callee voice files and path
    ofstream callerVoiceFile;
    ofstream calleeVoiceFile;   
    string outFilePath;
    string log;
    ofstream logFile;
    string startTime;
    string endTime;
    string length;
}
```

commented line in copy constructor raises the same error, i.e. Error C2249

```
VOIP::VOIP(const VOIP & voip)
    /*:calleePort(voip.calleePort), calleeVoiceFile(voip.calleeVoiceFile), calleeVoiceVector(voip.calleeVoiceVector),
     callerPort(voip.callerPort), callerVoiceFile(voip.callerVoiceFile), callerVoiceVector(voip.callerVoiceVector),
     callType(voip.callType), endTime(voip.endTime), length(voip.length), log(voip.log), logFile(voip.logFile),
     outFilePath(voip.outFilePath), startTime(voip.startTime),
     pleaseDial(voip.pleaseDial), DLHmm(voip.DLHmm)//signalings*///TODO
{
    cout<<"inside copy constractor"<<endl;
}

VOIP::~VOIP(void)
{
    callerVoiceVector.clear();
    calleeVoiceVector.clear();
    callerVoiceFile.close();
    calleeVoiceFile.close();
    logFile.close();
    cout<<"inside destractor"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: `Face Error C2249 raises from line "?"`? That made absolutely no sense.

Comment: @jalf Actually it does. He meant the error with code C2249 raised from this line `calls.erase(it);//"?"`

Comment: The `vector` can't reassign the `VOIP` object as its `ofstream` member is non-copyable.

Comment: Also, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). You'll get a badge (c:

Comment: This all depends on the details of class `VOIP`, which you haven shown.

Comment: Please paste the error message. C2249 is "'member' : no accessible path to access member declared in virtual base 'class'" but which member and which class?

Comment: class VOIP
{
public:
 VOIP(string SourceDirectoryPath, string startTime, signalling sig, int callerIp[], int calleeIp[], int callerPort, int calleePort);
 VOIP(const VOIP & voip);
 ~VOIP(void);
 vector<u_char> callerVoiceVector;
 vector<u_char> calleeVoiceVector;
 ofstream callerVoiceFile;
 ofstream calleeVoiceFile; 
 string outFilePath;
 string log;
 ofstream logFile;
 string startTime;
 string endTime;
 string length;}

Comment: @Habib You should edit your question and add that to the question itself, not to a comment. As you can see, the comment is very difficult to read.

Comment: Could you please show us how is `~VOIP()` implemented? It is the only source for this error that I can think of.

Comment: As @R.MartinhoFernandes asked, we would also need you to copy here the exact wording of the error message you get.

Comment: Error 10 error C2249: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::operator =' : no accessible path to private member declared in virtual base 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream

Answer (score 1):

The standard library containers require, in general, that the objects they contain can be copy constructible and copy assignable. This is, they require access to the copy constructor (in your case, `VOIP::VOIP(const VOIP&)`) and the copy assignment operator (in your case, `VOIP::operator=(const VOIP&)`). If your class does not provide them explicitly, these functions are automatically generated by your compiler as long as it can do it: this is, as long as all class members are also copy constructible or copy assignable, which is not the case for `VOIP`, since `ofstream` cannot be copied.

Nevertheless, `VOIP` provides an explicit copy constructor, so no problems there. This is the reason why `vector<VOIP>::push_back()`, which needs the copy constructor, works. Unfortunately it does not provide a copy assignment operator and, strange as it seems, `vector<VOIP>::erase()` needs it. The reason is that, when you erase an element from the vector, all elements after it must be copied to the previous position in order to fill the gap. And this is what the error message is telling you: `ofstream` is not copyable because its base class `std::basic_ios<>` is not copyable, so `VOIP` is not copyable.

To solve your problem, you may provide a copy assignment operator for `VOIP` following the same ideas you used for the copy constructor. Incidentally, in C++ there is something called the *rule of three*: if a class has a explicit destructor, copy constructor or copy assignment operator, it usually needs all three of them. `VOIP` has the first two, but misses the third. Write it and everything will be fine.